# django- Exception Value: No module named urls

Tags: python, django, module, python-import

I have created a `urls` and `views` folder, like `templates`, but it is not working.
I am getting error: 
`Exception Value: No module named urls`

Here's what my project looks like:

requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.6.5
pymongo==2.8
```

.

```
├── DjangoProject
│   ├── DjangoProject
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   │   ├── urls
│   │   │   │   └── test.py
│   │   │   └── views
│   │   │       └── test.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── wsgi.py
│   │   └── wsgi.pyc
│   └── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

settings.py file :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'DjangoProject.app',
     ........
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoProject.app.urls'
```

DjangoProject/urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('DjangoProject.app.urls')),  
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

app/urls/test.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
urlpatterns = patterns('DjangoProject.app.views.test',
        url(r'^/create/$','first_view',name='first_view'),
)
```

app/views/test.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.template import RequestContext

def first_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hi")
```

Comment: I don't understand what you've called your url and views files. Are they really both called test.py, inside directories called urls and views? If so why?

Comment: yes,both called test.py, inside directories called urls and views. my plan is to create one major app and inside that different apps which gets call by links, like webmaster. will __init__.py will help me for this?

Comment: Well, don't. Move those files into the app directory and call them what they are, urls.py and views.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to make it work like a module try adding `__init__.py`
in both of url and views folder with the following content

```
from .test import *
```

To explain it further in terms of your question `__init__.py` will be placed in the `DjangoProject/DjangoProject/app/urls/` and `DjangoProject/DjangoProject/app/views/`.

To use `ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoProject.app.urls'` you will have to import everything into the `__init__.py` file as well.

For the use case of importing views as seen here.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
urlpatterns = patterns('DjangoProject.app.views.test',        
    url(r'^/create/$','first_view',name='first_view'),
)
```

you don't even have to import anything in the `__init__.py` of views.

Comment: http://pythoncentral.io/package-python-django-application-reusable-component/   OR   https://110j.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/organize-django-applications/

Comment: the above two is link i found. i want to create module(folder) for views and urls for  one major app. i understood that __init__.py will help me this but, i dont know how? will you elaborate this to me? and also is my ROOT_URLCONF in settings.py and  url in DjangoProject/urls.py is right?

Comment: the `__init__.py` file will go into every folder which you want to use as module. So in this case it will go into `DjangoProject/DjangoProject/app/urls/__init__.py` and similarly for views folder.

also you will have to import things into  the `__init__.py` that you want to access at the module level.

Comment: you are right...thank you mr. pyvkd. simply genius. you save me from drowning. i am in the air~~~

Answer (score 0):

The idea from django architecture is to have a file for urls and views for every app. Remember that `urls.py` stores all the urls from the app, if you want to extend it, try creating another app. What I suggest is removing that folder with both `tests.py` and structuring the file directly into your DjangoApp folder.

Also, as the comment above says correctly, for python to treat a folder like a module you should create a file called `__init__.py`, check out [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for).

Answer (score 0):

Your application file structure and your configuration has problems.
read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

for instance:
You should assign your function in view.py to its url so in this line:

```
url(r'^/create/$','first_view',name='first_view'),
```

change it to:

```
url(r'^/create/$', views.first_view, name='first_view'),
```